# why my external css file not loading with html file on my tomcat server

Tags: java, html, css, eclipse, servlets

I am beginner and I don't know why my external studentinformation.css file is not loading when I run my Signup.html on tomcat 3.2 or above but loads when I right click and open my html file with the chrome browser. Both of my html and css files are in WEB-INF folder.
No error in the console for css. [A screeshot for the reference of my eclipse ide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vdOK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the (.) and the (/) when linking to your css file.

Comment: Yes I did but no change

Answer (score 0):

I tried on latest version of tomcat server v10.0 and my external css works fine on it. Older versions of tomcat only runs internal and inline css.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. wrap your html and css files in a file named (for example: presentation )
2. put presentation file under webapp folder
3. let your index.html be located under webapp without wrapping it in the presentation file. (addressing in index.html must be like: href:"presentation/style.css")
4. make sure to perform "mvn clean" and prevent browser from caching the previous contents in order to get the proper result.